# grunt Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: json, gruntjs

i try grunt on my windows machine. if i use yo webapp all work fine, but if i try to use grunt on exist project i have some problem.

### my Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
banner:"<%= pkg.name %>"
});
//Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
//grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.log.writeln("____________ log __________________");
grunt.log.writeln(grunt.pkg.name);
grunt.log.writeln(grunt.pkg.banner);
grunt.log.writeln();
grunt.log.writeln();
// Default task(s).
grunt.registerTask('default');}
```

package.json

```
{
"name": "bsworld",
"version": "0.1.0",
"description": "mio progetto personale",
"devDependencies": {
"grunt": "^0.4.1"
},
"engines": {
"node": ">=0.10.0"
},
"scripts": {
"test": "grunt test"
}
}
```

this is the output of grunt --verbose

> Initializing
>   Command-line options: --verbose
>   Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK
>   Registering Gruntfile tasks.
>   Initializing config...OK
>   **______** log **____________**
>   Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>       >> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
>       >>     at Object.module.exports (C:\Apache\htdocs\bottonisworld.com\Gruntfile.js:13:29)
>
> > ```
> > at loadTask (C:\Apache\htdocs\bottonisworld.com\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt    \task.js:325:10)
> > at Task.task.init (C:\Apache\htdocs\bottonisworld.com\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\task.js:437:5)
> > at Object.grunt.tasks (C:\Apache\htdocs\bottonisworld.com\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt.js:120:8)
> > at Object.module.exports [as cli] (C:\Apache\htdocs\bottonisworld.com\node_modules\grunt\lib\grunt\cli.js:38:9)
> > at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\l.bottoni\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt:45:20)
> > at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
> > at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
> > at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
> > at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
> > ```
> >
> > No tasks specified, running default tasks.
> >        Running tasks: default
> >        Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.
> >        Aborted due to warnings.

## why grunt don' load the file json?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved, the json is loaded but i must get data with the correct method

```
grunt.log.writeln(grunt.config("pkg.name"));
```